# Wrong gas estimation when using tx.gasprice

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethers.js, gas-price, gas-estimate

I use `tx.gasprice` and `block.basefee` in my Smart Contract to calculate how much eth the User spent, to send the spent amount back to the Relayer, because I am using meta Transactions.

Now I wanted to set the `gasLimit` of my contract to the estimated Gas amount(to make the calculation in my smart contract as perfect as possible), but now I ran into a problem:

I can't estimate Gas when using `tx.gasprice`, because it only shows me that it spent ~92k gas, but in reality, the tx spent 190k-200k.

[image]

So when i set `test = true`, the below code shows me only ~92k gas spent:

> let estGas = await forwarder.estimateGas.execute(request, signature);

Also, when I set `test = false` it shows me a closer estimated gas amount of ~225k.

[image]

[image]

Here is [one example tx on goerli](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x5ba5bab8bffa4d013b6a2c2d17d7ceadf24131f502c325abea862d4b418e77bf), everything works fine when I set the gasLimit to 300k besides that I get a wrong `estimateGas()` amount in javascript.

---

The same problem happens with `transfer` function which calls the modifier `payGasFees()`: when I set `test = true`, I get an error message and if I set it `test = false` everything works besides `estimatedGas()`

> let estimatedGas = await myContract.estimateGas.transfer(chosenToken, amountInMaximum, fee, true, token, transferTo, _amount,{from: from, gasLimit: 300000});

[image]

---

So to Summarize everything:

The estimateGas function from ethers or web3 are not working when I use tx.gasprice in my smart contract.

I don't know why it's not working and idk how to solve this issue.
It would be nice if someone have any idea or the same issue, I have no clue how to solve this problem.
If you need more code to help me please let me know.

---

Code:

```js
export async function signMetaTxRequest(signer, forwarder, input) {

    let request = await buildRequest( forwarder, input);
    const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
    const signature = await signTypedData2(signer, input.from, toSign);
    let estGas = await forwarder.estimateGas.execute(request, signature);
    console.log("estGas: ", estGas);
    console.log("estGas as Number: ", estGas.toNumber());
    return { signature, request };
}

export async function buildRequest(forwarder, input) {

    const nonce = await forwarder.getNonce(input.from).then(nonce => nonce.toString());
    return { value: 0, gas: 300000, nonce, ...input };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to another network(matic) and it works perfectly, so the problem is probably goerli or maybe in general all testnets.

I will post a upadte as soon I can estimate the issue correctly

Comment: ok, i made a mistake, it still doesn't work, i can't estimate the gas at all, even when i try to estimate the gas for the below function i get an "unpredicatable gas fee" error:

function getPrice() external {
        gasprice = tx.gasprice;
    }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).